# MVC Pattern - How to get errors from the model to the controller?

Tags: object-oriented, mvc, object-oriented-design, validation

Say I have a typical MVC setup. The controller passes on some input to the model, and asks it to do something with it. But the validation of the data fails, or there is some other problem. What's the best way of getting these errors passed back to the controller, which will then pass them to the view to be displayed to the user?

At the moment, I just have an `errors` array in my model. When any errors occur, I simply add the error messages to this array, and `return false` to the controller, so it knows that errors occurred. And in the controller, I do this:

```
boolean result = model.process( input );

if (! result)
{
   view.displayErrors( model.getErrors() );
   return;
}
else
   view.displaySuccess();
```

Is there a better way of handling this?

Comment: exceptions, separate statefull error checking has been dated since exceptions came up

Comment: @ratchetfreak How would that work for multiple error messages?

Comment: state in the exception, create your own custom exception that can take multiple error messages

Comment: Can you explain why you are unhappy with your current approach?

Comment: @mortalapeman I'm just looking to see if there's a better way.

Comment: related: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/97880/in-mvc-should-a-model-handle-validation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So what you're suggesting / currently doing is one method, and it's certainly a valid way of gathering additional information about error messages.

It's a reasonably lightweight approach - the caller gets a success | failure message and then it's up to the caller to dig deeper for additional information if it so cares.  The downside is what you alluded to with the comments - what if there are multiple issues within the validation?

It wouldn't be too hard to extend this approach so that the caller loops over a `GetErrorDetails()` call until that method returns an indicator of "no more errors."

Another *potential* issue with this approach is the implicit assumption that the caller is in the best position to deal with whatever the error messages may be.  Since you're using MVC, the controller *isn't* always the best layer to fix that problem.  The validation errors need to be pushed back to the View so the user can correct the issue.  I'm not focusing on this aspect since there are some valid counter-arguments to indicate that the Controller could / should indicate the error.  *That* discussion is not the point of your question.

**Altertnative 1**
As an alternative, consider making a full blown object to return errors with.  Instead of the boolean that you're currently returning, you'll return that error object instead.

Obviously, the error object will need to have a value to indicate success | failure | partial-success | whatever.  The benefit is that you can now add a collection of errors within the error object itself.

Here's some pseudo-code to give you an idea of what I'm suggesting.

```
ErrorParent()
{
  bool success;
  List errorMsgs;
}

ErrorMessages()
{
  string message;
  int  severity;
  List callstack;
}
```

The caller has to work a little harder to determine success, but it's an equally simple `ErrorParent.success` check as opposed to a `success` check.  Yes, yes, I know the troubles of typing out a few more characters...

If the caller cares about the errors, then it can iterate over the `ErrorParent.errorMsgs` collection and see what all went wrong.  If the caller *doesn't care* about the errors then it can pass the error object off to an error handler and let the handler do all the hard work.

**Alternative 2**
Instead of returning a bool for success / error, you could return a numeric value.  The numeric value would indicate the number of failed validations.  The Controller could pass that numeric error return to the "best" error handler for that situation, and then the error handler would loop over the `GetErrorDetails()` method.